# Error when using two matching foreignKeys in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an inventory management system in django for keeping track of equipment used in the live events area, and I have been hitting this error when I attempt to makemigrations.

I have looked hard for typos (as all the solutions I have found have been typo related) and wasn't able to find anything. I'm assuming that this has something to do with using the same foreign key twice.

```py
from django.db import models
from .tools import barutils
from .tools import types as choices


class venue(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)


class location(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


class type(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=124, blank=False)


class item(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    location = models.ForeignKey(location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="current_location")
    home = models.ForeignKey(location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="home_location")
    out = models.BooleanField(null=True)
```

The code above produces this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Documents\Home\Programming\Active\Vento\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 786, in __init__
    to._meta.model_name
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute '_meta'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Documents\Home\Programming\Active\Vento\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\Documents\Home\Programming\Active\Vento\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "F:\Documents\Home\Programming\Active\Vento\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "F:\Documents\Home\Programming\Active\Vento\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "F:\Documents\Home\Programming\Active\Vento\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "F:\Documents\Home\Programming\Active\Vento\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "F:\Documents\Home\Programming\Active\Vento\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "F:\Documents\Home\Programming\Active\Vento\dashboard\models.py", line 23, in <module>
    class item(models.Model):
  File "F:\Documents\Home\Programming\Active\Vento\dashboard\models.py", line 27, in item
    home = models.ForeignKey(location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="home_location")
  File "F:\Documents\Home\Programming\Active\Vento\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 792, in __init__
    RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT,
AssertionError: ForeignKey(<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

Comment: can you try to change the name of your classes to start with Capital ? That may be a problem

Comment: You locally scope a variable named `location`, and thus it will take the location of the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets explain it using `location` and 'venue' classes:

```py
class venue(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)

class location(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

You want to reference the `venue` to its class but it has the same name as the field (`venue`) that you have defined for `location`. so it will consider that instead of the model class .
So that is not a django model and will fail.

Try to change the name of the classes to their `CamelCase` type and set their fields which are foreign keys using underline.

So it would be like this:

```py
class Venue(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)


class Location(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Type(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=124, blank=False)


class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="current_location")
    home = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="home_location")
    out = models.BooleanField(null=True)
```

Comment: I'm so dissapointed that I didn't spot this, thank you very much!

Comment: It was my pleasure

Answer (score 2):

Please use the [**PEP-008**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) styling guidelines. These specify that classes are written in `CamelCase`, and attributes in `lowercase_with_underscores`. The rules are a bit more complex, but that is the general idea. For more sophisticated cases, you should better look at the PEP-008 document itself.

Right now you mix the two. As a result, if you use `location` *after* you defined it, you refer to the `ForeignKey` instance already defined. You thus can fix your code with:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)


class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=124, blank=False)


class Item(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="current_location")
    home = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="home_location")
    out = models.BooleanField(null=True)
```

Other remarks:

> **Note**: Django autoamtically adds an `AutoField` that is a primary key named `id` if you do not specify a primary key yourself, you thus can omit the primary key.